# C# application on dual monitors, reverts to single monitor after screen lock

Tags: c#-3.0, multiple-monitors

I have an issue with one of my c# applications, it has a single form which is stretched over two monitors and works fine, however if I lock the screen and come back to it, the application reverts to a single screen view.

I was wondering if anyone had come across something like this before or knew why this was happening?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the second screen is disabled during the desktop is locked.
If you now log in again, the form will reinitialize it's position before the second monitor is activated again.

[This small article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/restoreposition.aspx) might help you, to solve the problem :)